# Commenting out Printf Cause Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

I have been stuck for a while on a statement that causes a segmentation fault when commented out, from some of the information about this that I gathered people were saying that my stack was getting corrupted somewhere or somehow.

http://pastebin.com/NT8PGPi0

the code that cause the segmentation fault line number 511 (sorry for all the newlines linux didn't like when I copied it out of the editor)

basically with this project it should be able to print a .txt to the screen with different options chosen by the user for instance

./a.out --delete=c // deletes all the c's in the file and spots it to the console
./a.out --line-numbers // posts all the line numbers in the console

so on and so forth with the long options, same with the short options.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and also perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). You may have a memory corruption or some undefined behavior. Don't expect us to do your homework. Read about [toupper(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/toupper.3.html)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, the best option in such situation is always debug code by gdb or another debuger. But as a small hint. Look at this in Opt_Args function:

```
    *c = getc(fp);
```

And then look at manual for getc:

```
  int getc(FILE *stream);
```